# Classification of degree $p$ field extensions of characteristic $p$ fields: the non-normal but separable case

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, splitting-field

When thinking about [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428322/fields-with-restrictions-on-their-finite-extensions-given-n-in-mathbbn-1) I thought about degree $p$ extensions of a field $F$ of $\text{char}(F)=p>0$.

In general we distinguish finite extensions according to the properties normal and separable.

We know that [purely inseparable extensions are normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871226/whats-an-example-of-a-non-normal-purely-inseparable-field-extension). Although [there are non-normal inseparable extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242542/example-of-an-non-normal-inseparable-field-extension?rq=1) they cannot be of degree $p$, because the inseparable part "takes up all of the degree p" and thus an inseparable degree $p$ extension must be purely inseparable. Such extensions are given by an irreducible polynomial of the form $X^p-\alpha$ for $\alpha\in F$. This classifies these extensions up to the question for which $\alpha\in F$ the polynomial $X^p-\alpha$ is irreducible.

According to [Artin-Schreier theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory) all normal separable degree $p$ extensions (i.e. Galois extensions and in this case in particular cyclic extensions) are given by an irreducible polynomial of the form $X^p-X-\alpha$ for $\alpha\in F$. This classifies these extensions up to the question for which $\alpha\in F$ the polynomial $X^p-X-\alpha$ is irreducible.

The remaining class are non-normal separable degree $p$ extensions. Playing around with [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) I found such an extension over $F=\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ given by $f=X^p-tX-1$ for $p=3$ - see code below: Magma tells us that the defining polynomial should have an order $6$ Galois group. **Jyrki Lahtonen** eluminates this by an explanation in the comments showing that this extension is indeed non-normal separable of degree $p$. Experimentially this type of polynomial seems to work for all primes $2\neq p\leq 41$ where I stopped searching because of the time restrictions of the free Magma calculator.

```
p := 3;
E<t> := FunctionField(GF(p));
R<X> := PolynomialRing(E);
F<a> := FunctionField(X^p-t*X-1);
F;
Characteristic(F);
Degree(F);
f := DefiningPolynomial(F);
G := GaloisGroup(f);
Order(G);
```

My question is: **Is there a nice classification for non-normal separable degree $p$ extensions?** Is such a classification parallel to the other two cases, i.e. are such extensions given by polynomials of a certain standard form?

**Some results:**

- Any extension of a finite field is always normal and separable for arbitrary degree. Even better, for every fixed degree $n$ there is a unique degree $n$ extension up to isomorphism. Thus degree $p$ extension can easily be classified: there is exactly one such extension and it is of Artin-Schreier type.
- Any extension of degree $2$ is necessarily normal. So in case of characteristic $2$ any extension is either of Artin-Schreier type or purely inseparable. This seems to be one of the few cases where the "$2$ is the oddest prime"-exceptionalism works in favor of simplifying the question instead of complicating it.

**Remarks:**

- Forming the composite field of a non-normal separable $p$-extension (as above) with a purely inseparable $p^{n-1}$-extension we get non-normal inseparable extension of degree $p^n$, so for any $p$-power. The example linked above of a non-normal inseparable extension has degree $15$ and is thus not a $p$-power.
- Forming the composite field of several non-normal separable $p$-extensions defined by $n$ suitable extensions one should get a non-normal inseparable extension of degree $p^n$, so for any $p$-power. Suitable here means that one has to avoid configurations analog to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt[3]{6})/\mathbb{Q}$, which will not be an extension of degree $3^3$. I don't have a proof that such extensions really exist for every $p^n$, i.e. that there are enough suitable non-normal separable $p$-extensions, neither in general nor for an example field.

These remarks show how an answer to the question is useful to a more general study of field extensions.

**Update:** The question was rewritten in light of some computer experiments and comments on that.

Comment: This is a natural question, but I'm not sure what can be said. Quite likely I'm the wrong person to attempt to answer! Anyway, I cannot shake the feeling that, in a sense, most degree $p$ extensions are neither normal nor inseparable. Therefore expecting a classification may be asking too much. Inseparable and cyclic extensions are somehow exceptional, and can be classified. The same applies to finite fields with even extra force. Comparison of $p=3$ cases with random irreducible cubics over $\Bbb{Q}$ may still be misguided, but in the latter case we expect the Galois group to be full $S_3$.

Comment: (cont'd) The cyclic cases are rare. It's the same here. Adjoining a single zero of a random irreducible cubic probably won't give a normal extension.

Comment: Mind you, I do find your example cubic interesting. Well designed! I cannot resist the temptation to point out that it is also a nice illustration of Galois theory in action. If you first extend $E=\Bbb{F}_3(x)$ to $K=E(\sqrt x)$ (obviously a quadratic Galois extension), then you can rewrite the cubic equation
$$y^3-xy-1=0$$
in the form
$$(\frac y{\sqrt x})^3-(\frac y{\sqrt x})-\frac1{(\sqrt x)^3}=0.$$
Revealing the Artin-Schreier nature of the extension $F(\sqrt x)/K$. This was, of course fully expected. If $y$ is one zero of that cubic, $y\pm1/\sqrt x$ are the other two.

Comment: (cont'd) And Galois theory promised that we get the splitting field $F(\sqrt x)$ as a tower of a cyclic quadratic extension followed by a cyclic cubic extension - the latter necessarily of the Artin-Schreier form.

Comment: Whatever the field $K$ is with $\prod_{j=1}^n (T-x_j)=\sum_{m=0}^n a_m T^m$ then $K(x_1,\ldots,x_n)/K(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ is Galois with Galois group $S_n$ so you'll find any kind of separable extension in characteristic $p$